# Match a row with fixed columns as long as possible

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, text-parsing, string-parsing

I'm going to parse a position base file from a legacy system. Each column in the file has a fixed column width and each row can maximum be 80 chars long. The problem is that you don't know how long a row is. Sometime they only have filled in the first five columns, and sometimes all columns are used.

If I KNOW that all 80 chars where used, then I simple could do like this:

```
^\s*
 (?<a>\w{3})
 (?<b>[ \d]{2})
 (?<c>[ 0-9a-fA-F]{2})
 (?<d>.{20})
 ...
```

But the problem with this is that if the last columns is missing, the row will not match. The last column can even be less number of chars then the maximum of that column.

See example

```
Text to match         a   b  c  d
"AQM45A3A text   " => AQM 45 A3 "A text   "  //group d has 9 chars instead of 20
"AQM45F5"          => AQM 45 F5              //group d is missing
"AQM4"             => AQM  4                 //group b has 1 char instead of 2
"AQM4  ASome Text" => AQM  4  A "Some Text"  //group b and c only uses one char, but fill up the gap with space
"AQM4FSome Text"   => No match, group b should have two numbers, but it is only one.
"COM*A comment"    => Comments do not match (all comments are prefixed with COM*)
"       "          => Empty lines do not match
```

How should I design the Regular Expression to match this?

**Edit 1**

In this example, EACH row that I want to parse, is starting with AQM

- Column a is always starting at position 0
- Column b is always starting at position 3
- Column c is always starting at position 5
- Column d is always starting at position 7

If a column is not using all its space, is files up with spaces
Only the last column that is used can be trimed

**Edit 2**
To make it more clearer, I enclose here soem exemple of how the data might look like, and the definition of the columns (note that the examples I have mentioned earlier in the question was heavily simplified)

[image: Example for AQM]
[image: Definition for AQM]

Comment: Your requirements are not really clear. Which rows of your example should match and which shouldn't? And why?

Comment: Sorry. All the rows in the example should match. The task is to get all columns that are present on each row. I add some more examples to show row that do not match

Comment: The main problem in your situation is the lack of any clear separator between the columns, what could qualify a certain character to be in this or that column since character number in each column is variable ?

Comment: The number of chars in each column is fixed, except for the last column. The last column can be trimed

Comment: I added a new example of columns that are shorter and fill up the gap with spaces

Comment: You want to do this with regex? There are a couple of ways you could do that (with regex), but it can get lengthy.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure a regexp is the right thing to use here. If I understand your structure, you want something like

```
if (length >= 8) 
   d = everything 8th column on
   remove field d
else
   d = empty

if (length >= 6)
   c = everything 6th column on
   remove field c
else
   c = empty
```

etc. Maybe a regexp can do it, but it will probably be rather contrived.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `?` after the groups which could not be there. In this case if some group is missing you would have the match.

**Edit n, after Sguazz answer**

I would use

```
(?<a>AQM)(?<b>[ \d]{2})?(?<c>[ 0-9a-fA-F]{2})?(?<d>.{0,20})?
```

or even a `+` instead of the `{0,20}` for the last group, if could be that there are more than 20 chars.

**Edit n+1,**

Better like this?

```
(?<a>\w{3})(?<b>\d[ \d])(?<c>[0-9a-fA-F][ 0-9a-fA-F])(?<d>.+)
```

Comment: Ok, I edit, even if your comment then will be puzzling for who is going to read it later.

Comment: I have try do do that, but whats happening when they have timed the last column

Comment: If you put ? after each group, each column become optional. But no column is optional. I KNOW that column d always start at position 7 if it exist.

Comment: Ok, so just use the `(?<d>.+)` and forget about the `?` for the other groups. Maybe use `\d[ \d]` instead of `[ \d]{2}`, so the number of consumed columns is correct and you avoid to have only spaces.

Comment: Sorry I'm so vague.
What I mean that it is the last USED column that can be shortened. Which column however is unknown. They may only use the first 2-3 columns, you never know.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. You have groups starting at fixed columns. These groups could be made of spaces, just to fill their columns. Then you want to catch the full line, grouping correctly the groups, but you don't want comments (`COM...`) and only spaces. Have I it right?

Comment: yep, so far, I think you have understood it.

Comment: In addition to what you have already written, the line may be less than the maximum 80 characters. You do not know how many characters are missing. The row can be everything from 80 to 3 characters long. Either way, the line is matched.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35929/discussion-between-davide-and-magol)

Answer (score 1):

So, just to rephrase: in your example you have a sequence of character, and you know that the first 3 belong to group A, the following 2 belong to group B, then 2 to group C and 20 to group D, but there might not be this many elements.

Try with:

```
(?<a>\w{0,3})(?<b>[ \d]{0,2})(?<c>[ 0-9a-fA-F]{0,2})(?<d>.{0,20})
```

Basically these numbers are now an upper limit of the group as opposed to a fixed size.

EDIT, to reflect your last comment: if you know that all your relevant rows start with 'AQM', you can replace group A with `(?<a>AQM)`

ANOTHER EDIT: Let's try with this instead.

```
(?<a>AQM)(?<b>[ \d]{2}|[ \d]$)(?<c>[ 0-9a-fA-F]{0,2})(?<d>.{0,20})
```

Comment: I have also thought about doing this. The problem is that you then can not guarantee that the columns get fixed widths.

Comment: I thought you meant that the LAST row might not have a fixed width; the others fill up with spaces which are really just another character. Is that not right?

Comment: Also - maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but I'm having a hard time finding a row that fails. Are you able to provide one?

Comment: Each row is matching individual. It is the last USED COLUMN that can be trimmed. But you don't know wish column that is the latest. I have add a new example that do not match

Comment: Ah, I see. How's this one?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a function like this one to break the string into its column values. It doesn't parse comment strings and is able to handle strings that are shorter than 80 characters. It doesn't validate the contents of the columns though. Maybe you can do that when you use the values.

```
/// <summary>
/// Break a data row into a collection of strings based on the expected column widths.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">The width delimited input data to break into sub strings.</param>
/// <returns>
/// An empty collection if the input string is empty or a comment.
/// A collection of the width delimited values contained in the input string otherwise.
/// </returns>
private static IEnumerable<string> ParseRow(string input) {
    const string COMMENT_PREFIX = "COM*";
    var columnWidths = new int[] { 3, 2, 2, 3, 6, 14, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 10, 7, 7, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1 };
    int inputCursor = 0;
    int columnIndex = 0;
    var parsedValues = new List<string>();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || input.StartsWith(COMMENT_PREFIX) || input.Trim().Length == 0) {
        return parsedValues;
    }

    while (inputCursor < input.Length && columnIndex < columnWidths.Length) {
        //Make sure the column width never exceeds the bounds of the input string. This can happen if the input string doesn't end on the edge of a column.
        int columnWidth = Math.Min(columnWidths[columnIndex++], input.Length - inputCursor);
        string columnValue = input.Substring(inputCursor, columnWidth);
        parsedValues.Add(columnValue);
        inputCursor += columnWidth;
    }
    return parsedValues;
}
```